# how to calculate line height from psd file? (leading+ font size)

Tags: html, css, css-float, photoshop

I have this psd and trying to convert it to html css.

But I can't calculate the line height in css from the psd.

How can i calculate the line height from the leading + font size?

thanks

Comment: Has the `leading` value been set in Photoshop, or is it on `auto`?

Comment: the leading value been set in Photoshop.

Comment: For reference, this question was also answered here:  http://superuser.com/questions/607171/how-to-calculate-line-height-from-psd-file

Answer (score 23):

If leading is not auto :  LineHeight = font size + Leading / 2

---

If leading is auto : LineHeight = 120% of the font size

Answer (score 0):

If font-size 14px and line height in photoshop 24px then divide "photoshop's line height" by 2 
Exaple:

14 + 24/2 = 26px

Comment: I'm newer and find this some days ago, that's why i have added here.